# Illogical ArgumentOutOfRangeException in ObservableCollection with index within range

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm using an `ObservableCollection` (`_queue`) as a queue to show a stream of items. I have a non-async `next` method with the following relevant code fragment:

```
if (_queue.Count > 0) {
    try {
        playingTrack = _queue[0];
        _queue.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to remove first of queue size="+_queue.Count);
    }
}
```

Note the (temporary) general catch which should not be necessary. I tend to catch the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown by `RemoveAt` seemingly at random, even though the index zero should be valid given the preceding condition and that the indexing succeeded. Even so, the debug message always shows up showing a size > 0. The exception has happened so far only when the above method was called by `MediaElement.MediaEnded` all within the UI thread.

After reading up and down on msnd I still haven't found any documentation about this behavior. Does anybody have an idea of what could be happening here?

Comment: you mention Windows store. Could another thread be removing something while you're in this code?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question by itself could never cause this exception because it properly guards the access against the count.  Hence the only explanation is that code not mentioned in the question is causing the exception to occur.  The most likely cause is either

1. Multiple threads
2. Event handler code for the collection

Given that this is an `ObservableCollection<T>` my guess is #2 is the most likely.  Essentially some code which is looking for a change in the collection is mistakenly accessing a value that is no longer valid.  If this is the case that code will be at the very top of the stack when the exception is thrown.

Comment: The way `CollectionChangedEventArgs` works also supports this theory; it points to indices of changed objects - so any class listening to the `CollectionChanged` event will want to access the added object by index.

Comment: That sounds plausible... however there's no mention of thread safety for these classes that I've found so far. I'll dig deeper into the stack traces as soon as I can break my app again.

Comment: I have a similar issue, however I am _adding_ elements to the collection, but never remove any, and the method throwing the exception is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Insert(int, T)` with a plausible index, however it is way off compared to `Count` by ~10000.